# Google Colaboratory NotFoundError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_text/python/metrics/_text_similarity_metric_ops.so

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, google-colaboratory

I have an issue when importing Top2vec (In colab notebook).
To reproduce it:

```
pip install top2vec[sentence_encoders]
```

Restart the runtime to load new modules, Then

```
from top2vec import Top2Vec
```

It shows me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-9a81163f0da9> in <module>()
----> 1 from top2vec import Top2Vec

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py in load_op_library(library_filename)
     55     RuntimeError: when unable to load the library or get the python wrappers.
     56   """
---> 57   lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
     58   try:
     59     wrappers = _pywrap_python_op_gen.GetPythonWrappers(

NotFoundError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_text/python/metrics/_text_similarity_metric_ops.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow15OpKernelContext15allocate_outputEN4absl14lts_2020_09_2311string_viewERKNS_11TensorShapeEPPNS_6TensorE
```

I've find the solution that says you should install
`pip install -U tensorflow==2.3.0` but this version is not compatible with top2vec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might due to the incompatibility of Tensorflow when using

```
!pip install top2vec[sentence_encoders]
```

I figured it out by first installing Top2Vec required version of TensorFlow and numpy:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.5.0
!pip install numpy
```

Then install Top2Vec and the pre-trained universal sentence encoder:

```
!pip install top2vec
!pip install top2vec[sentence_encoders]
```